# Singularity Container access external file for Build process

Tags: singularity-container

I need to install Cuda, CuDNN, and NCCL in a singularity container to build the MXNET Library for GPU Support. Currently, I have this minimal Definition File:

```
Bootstrap: library
From: ubuntu:20.04

%environment
    export CC=/usr/bin/gcc
    export CXX=/usr/bin/g++
    ... some other stuff


%post
    ... some other installation stuff
    
    apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
    wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu2004.pin
    mv cuda-ubuntu2004.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
    wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.2.0/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-2-local_11.2.0-460.27.04-1_amd64.deb
    dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-2-local_11.2.0-460.27.04-1_amd64.deb
    apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-2-local/7fa2af80.pub
    apt-get update
    apt-get -y install cuda
    export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.2/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.2/lib64\
                         ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
    /usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced --verbose
    
    ... clone and build mxnet
```

Installing Cuda is not a problem. However, in order to install CudNN, one first needs to log into an NVIDIA Account. Similarly, to install NCCL, one needs to complete a survey.

I obviously cannot do that per command line. But I can download these files beforehand. **How can I access these files in `%post`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`%files`](https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/3.10/user-guide/definition_files.html#files) section of the definition file. All files added there are available in `%post` and, if not moved, are included in the final image.

Answer (score 0):

[@tsnowlan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5791702/tsnowlan) gave a [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73109305/9406165).

For the others wondering, how to get Cuda, CuDNN, and NCCL easily into an singularity container:

There are Docker images from NVidia, that already come with these tools:
https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/cuda/tags

One can easily use these images as a base image for the docker container:
https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/3.0/user-guide/build_a_container.html